# how can I translate an array with react-native-i18n?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have my translation that goes like this:

en.json

```
{
   "Welcome": "Welcome to react native",
   "days": ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"]
}
```

and my page that it's like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import i18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import ReactNativeCalendar from 'react-native-calendar';
import translations from '../../translations';
import styles from './styles';

const dayHeadings = i18n.t('days');
```

[...]

```
const Calendar = (props) => {
  console.log(dayHeadings);
  return (
    <View>
      <ReactNativeCalendar
        customStyle={styles}
        nextButtonText={nextButton}
        prevButtonText={prevButton}
        dayHeadings={dayHeadings}
        monthNames={monthNames}
        onDateSelect={props.onDateSelect}
        eventDates={props.eventDates}
        showEventIndicators
        showControls
        events={props.events}
        calendarFormat={props.calendarFormat}
      />
      <Legend items={legendItems} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

dayHeadings is supposed to be an array of translated strings but instead I get

> missing "en.days" translation

from the console. The weird thing is that if I save the translation and trigger the hot reload the translation work just fine [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPIsh.png). Also the translation is present in the file [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4cSs.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way of doing it is to declare:

```
{
   "Welcome": "Welcome to React Native",
   "days": {
    "sun": "Sun",
    "mon": "Mon",
    "tue": "Tue",
    "wed": "Wed",
    "thu": "Thur",
    "fri": "Fri",
    "sat": "Sat"
  }
}
```

And then refer to it:

```
I18n.t(['days', 'mon']);
```

Assuming you want to display all the days (for instance in calendar), you go:

```
const dayKeys = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
...
render() {
  return (
    <View>
    {dayKeys.map((key) => <Text>{I18n.t(['days', key])}</Text>)}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: It didn't work in my case I don't know the exact reason but for the latest react native 0.50+ you can use it like this.                       
    {dayKeys.map((key) => <Text>{I18n.t('days'.${key})}</Text>)}

Answer (score 2):

In your i18n config, be sure to set `returnObjects: true`

example:

```
i18n
  ...
  .init({
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    backend: {
      loadPath: `...`,
    },
    returnObjects: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
```

and then your en json file would look like this...

```
{
  ...
  "days": ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
}
```